# Why multiplying probabilities of different events does not equal the actual probability of the different events occurring at the same time

Tags: probability

Given a set of randomly distributed integers $$(x_1,x_2,...x_N)$$ I would like to find the probability that adding each number to its index $$\ (x_1 +1,x_2+2,..x_N+N)$$ produces a set of numbers with the properties:

1. Has equal number of odd and even numbers
2. The sum of its even numbers equals $$\sum_{i=0}^N x_i$$
3. The sum of its odd numbers equals $$\sum_{i=0}^N i$$

I have run a million combination of exponentially distributed random numbers in Matlab, and found the probability of satisfying the first condition is 8.6%, the second condition is 0.06%, the third condition is 0.06%, and the probability of meeting all three at the same time is 0.02% (there were 208 cases in the million). I do not understand why the probability of meeting all three at the same time has come out to be greater than the product of meeting the 3 conditions separately, which comes out to around 0.03 in a million (8.6% x 0.06% x 0.06%).

Also, if I use a random number distribution I do not find any cases in the million where all three conditions are met. What does that imply for calculating the probability. Do I just need to run more cases?

Comment: The probability of multiple events occurring at the same time is only equal to the product of their probabilities when the events are independent. Here it is likely the case that the events are dependent.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense unless you define a distribution for the original set.